# How do I filter out words that have been separated by spaces?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am writing a word filter used by people, and as people do, they want to subvert the filter. For my purposes, I want to filter out the word "hello", but I also want to filter out "h e l l o" or "h.e.l.l.o" as well.

I've tried mucking about with word boundaries, but with no luck.

```
// works
message = message.replace(/\bhello\b/gi, "hello");
// doesn't
message = message.replace(/\bh\b\be\b\bl\b\bl\b\bo\b/gi, "hello");
```

Comment: What should happen to `"h.e l l.o"` (mix of dots and spaces)? Should this also match the regular expression or not?

Comment: @ChristianHujer Absolutely. :) I didn't even think I could have a regular expression that did both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression that you're looking for probably is `/\bh\W?e\W?l\W?l\W?o\b/`. You need an atom matching the space. \W is an atom matching non-word characters (opposite of alphanumeric). ? is a quantifier and allows for the preceding atom to be matched 0 or 1 times.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```
h[\W]*e[\W]*l[\W]*l[\W]*o
```

But gosh that's painful to write for many strings, and harder to read. You can build a basic string and use regex to make javascript write it's own regex string

```
// Pipe delimited list of words, surrounded by parentheses
var rwords = '(howdy|hello|organic)';
// Variable for easy manipulation, sets disallowed characters.
var anti = "[^a-z]*";
// Replace each character with the same followed by the character class contained in the 'anti' variable.
rwords = rwords.replace(/([a-z])/igm,'$1' + anti);
// Surround each side in word boundary markers
rwords = '\\b' + rwords + '\\b';
// Output the regex string as a sample, but you can create a regex object 
console.log(rwords);
```

Which you can use to create a regex object, and use that for your matching

You can edit the variable anti to hold okay characters. You might want to permit say, numbers, you'd change it to `[^a-z0-9]'

Comment: I don't know how the OP extrapolates to interstitial non-word, but if he ever runs into `h_ell_o` or `hell0` its all flubbed up.

Comment: @sln Flubbed up and deleted my comment, but you're absolutely right, [\W] would have permitted `_` which is the goto character for trying to bypass something (that and `.`). In this case, I'm thinking good old `a-z` is the better option, with a variable to hold the character class for easiest change.